# IIS AppPool identity denied access to move file

Tags: c#, .net, path, iis-7, access-denied

I have this exact (best as I can see) scenario on a test server and it works as expected.

IIS Application needs to move a file on the D drive from one sub folder to another subfolder

D:\supportfiles\new (file is here)
D:\supportfiles\backup (file needs to be moved here)

I gave the app pool **modify** access to the top level folder, D:\supportfiles
This works as expected on my test server, but not on a different server that I published to.  The app pool has permissions, or at least it appears it does.

I get this error

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.

```
File.Move(OldPath + FileName, NewPath + FileName);
```

Comment: Are you sure you gave access to the correct pool identity ? Also make sure the subfolders inherit the permissions from the top level one?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `OldPath`, `NewPath` and `FileName` when the exception occurs? The **exact** values - check in the `Watch` or `Immediate` Window. _Please copy and paste them from there, don't type them in._

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me. console application for sure. start as an administrator and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Go to advance settings of your application apppool and set it to LocalSystem instead of apppool identity. Or setup a new user specially for using in apppool. 
It's usually caused for some os hardening issues on product servers.